# How to Implement Push Notifcation in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

I have been working with ajax for a while now, and I have used it to do a lot of nifty jobs.. But then my recent challenge has been on push notification.

I want to implement a site that would not need to make a call to the server every period of time, but rather would make a call to the server only when there is an update on a particular DB field, and I want to implement this in  PHP, javascript and/or jquery or any other technology for the web. I do not have any idea as to how to go about it, or if it is even possible.

I would like directions on where and how to start, Thanks all.....

Comment: Web sockets or long polling.

Comment: web sockets, that should be HTML5 right, compatibility issues and all that

Comment: @GeorgeJames Yes, web sockets aren't yet supported very well. So you'd need to fall back on long polling. For .NET you would have SignalR for this, you might want to search for an PHP alternative.

Comment: Been doing a lot of research, I have not found anything appealing

Comment: Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/

Comment: Use this <a href="http://docs.recurly.com/api/push-notifications">Push notification</a> as reference. See the <a href="https://github.com/mbeale/recurly-push-notification-example">example</a>.

Comment: Server-sent events, half the duplex, twice the support of websockets : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Answer (score 0):

Since WebSocket support isn't quite there yet, you would want to fall back on long polling. There already seems to be a jQuery plugin for this:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/

A nice slide on this subject can be found here http://www.slideshare.net/ffdead/the-html5-websocket-api

To implement WebSockets in PHP, have a look at https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/