# jQuery AUTOMATIC scroll (no button click) on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, chat

I am creating a chat, everything works perfectly, it scrolls down when i click the "Send" button, but I want it to scroll all the way down when the document is ready. I have done this by adding the scrolling function to setInterval, but the problem with that is that the user basically cant scroll up to see previous chat messages because he gets scrolled down every 0.1 seconds. My code is:

```
    $(function () {

        //$("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages").prop("scrollHeight")); Doesnt work at all

        function updateChat(){
            $("#messages").load('chat/ajaxLoad.php');
            //$("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages").prop("scrollHeight")); This works but the user cannot scroll up anymore
        }

        setInterval(function () {
            updateChat();
        }, 100);


        $("#post").submit(function(){
            $.post("chat/ajaxPost.php", $('#post').serialize(), function (data) {
                $("#messages").append('<div>'+data+'</div>');
                $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages").prop("scrollHeight")); // This works but only when the user presses the send button
                $("#text").val("");
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: If there a reason why you have avoided $(document).ready()? From my understanding of what you want (that it would scroll to the bottom once everything has loaded), it's literally exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code.

```
var chat = $("#messages").html();
setInterval(function () {
    updateChat();
    if(chat !== $("#messages").html()){
        $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages").prop("scrollHeight"));
        chat = $("#messages").html();
    }
}, 2000);
```

I think this should work (didnt test), but there are some better ways you can optimise this like not saving the whole .html() into a variable.

The idea here is that it checks if the content is changed every 2 seconds. If it is, it scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

I see what's your problem and I have 2 ideas for you :

1. You scroll down only when a new message is post, for example with an Ajax request you could check if number of messages is > in compare with the last 0.1s, if yes you scroll if not you ignore.
2. You scroll down every 1-2s **only** if the scroll is at the maximum bottom position. If the scroll is not at the maximum you do not scroll. I feel this solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate the actions on your application, 
also you missed many checks that can make the application work properly and will
make it easy to maintain.

How i suggestion the code will look:

```
$(function () {

    function updateMessages(){
        var messages_before_update = $("#messages").html();
        $("#messages").load('chat/ajaxLoad.php');
        var message_after_update = $("#messages").html();
        if(messages_before_update !== message_after_update){
            scrollToBottom();
        }

    }

    function scrollToBottom(){
        var scroll_height = $("#messages").prop("scrollHeight");
        var scroll_top = $("#messages").scrollTop();
        if(scroll_height !== scroll_top){
            $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages").prop("scrollHeight"));
        }
    }

    function addMessage(message){
        $("#messages").append('<div>' + message + '</div>');
    }

    setInterval(updateMessages, 100);

    $("#post").submit(function () {
        $.post("chat/ajaxPost.php", $('#post').serialize(), function (data) {
            addMessage(data);
            scrollToBottom();
            $("#text").val("");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out! My free hosting service has reached 20,000 hits so I cant use the site until tomorrow. Thats the downside of using setInterval every 0.1 seconds haha

Comment: There are traditional ways to implement 'PUSH' (what you are trying to accomplish) that will require mush less requests!. you might want to google it.

Comment: This code does not scroll down automatically when the page is loaded.

Comment: okay. in the meantime, can you tell me more about those traditional ways of implementing PUSH funcitonality? i have searched and found nothing that is very clear.

Comment: This will require more then a comment to explain. But, I can refer you to a question here on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115114/how-to-implement-push-notifcation-in-php

Comment: You can user webSocket(tunneling/push), and "long pull" as fallback for browser that dose not support it.